# Sorting dictionary based on absolute value

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to sort a dictionary by the absolute value of its values without actually changing its values to absolute value.

For example, if we have a dict

```
my_dict = {(): 10, ("desk", "chair"): 4, ("coke"): -20}
```

I would want the final, sorted output to be

```
{("desk", "chair"): 4, (): 10, ("coke"): -20}
```

I've found a way to sort based on absolute value of dictionary through simple research

```
my_dict = {k, v for k,v in sorted(my_dict.items(), key = lambda dict_key: abs(my_dict[dict_key]))}
```

However, upon running I get `KeyError: ((): 10)`. I don't know how to modify my code cleanly to account for the empty values. Any ideas? I tried to look through other documentation and articles, but I couldn't find anything that accounted for this.

Comment: That's not the error you get.

Comment: `dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: abs(x[1])))`

Comment: `{k, v for` is a syntax error. In the future, for debugging help, you need to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do `key=lambda x: abs(x[1]))}`

```
my_dict = dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: abs(x[1])))
```

You can also try this

```
my_dict = {k: v for k,v in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]))}
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{('desk', 'chair'): 4, (): 10, 'coke': -20}
```